# Python modify variable by C

Tags: python, c, pointers, memory, cpython

Hello I would like to know if it is possible to modify the content of a python variable with its address with CPython or a Pointer ? If yes, how?

```
salut = "test"
id(salut) #address
hex(id(salut)) #address
```

Use C executable or dll

```
print(salut) //salut = "bonjour"
```

Comment: It's possible, but you *absolutely shouldn't do it* because it is wholly reliant on implementation details. Note, `id(salut)` is *not even guaranteed to return an address*. It just *happens* to return the address of the PyObject header, but this is an implementation detail. The only guarantee is that it returns an `int` that is unique for the lifetime of the object.

Comment: Note, Python doesn't really *have* pointers. In any case, it isn't clear exactly what you are trying to do.

Comment: So how can I get the PyObject and modify it via my executable?

Comment: It really isn't clear to me what you are asking. What are you trying to accomplish *exactly*? Note, you shouldn't be mutating `str` objects, they are *immutable*. Of course you *can* but that will probably break various assumptions in the runtime and lead to undefined behavior and subtle bugs

Comment: Also, it is important to understand, Python variables *are not like C variables*. Python variables are names in namespaces that refer to objects, they aren't chunks of memory, like in C. In any case, you really should elaborate on exactly what you are trying to do

Comment: What I want to do is declare a variable in my python code, then with my C DLL, get its PyObject via its address and modify it

Comment: Again, that isn't clear at all. What do you mean by "get its PyObject via its memory address and modify it"? What does that mean **exactly**? For example, why don't you just pass the object as a parameter to your function in your C DLL,?

Comment: For Python and C to share objects with each other, either (i) the Python code needs to be running in a Python interpreter hosted inside the C program, OR (ii) the C code needs to be part of an extension module, one of whose methods is invoked by the Python code.  Is either of these the case for you?

Comment: I think the better question here isn't what do you want to do but *why*. What's your bigger picture goal?

Comment: In fact my python code uses a C DLL that I created. And I would like that with a function in my DLL, I can modify the PyObject of a variable and modify it just with its memory address and not put it as a parameter.

Comment: @BleuNo **what do you mean by modify**?  You *cannot (should not) modify a `str` object*. So what exactly do you mean? Again, you *really* need to provide specific details here, in the question itself